# How to Generate Windows DLL versioning information with CMake

Tags: windows, dll, cmake

I'm using CMake to build a shared library, however for the Windows DLL I need the versioning information, like:

- FileDescription
- FileVersion
- InternalName
- LegalCopyright
- OriginalFilename
- ProductName
- ProductVersion

So far, all I have are the VERSION and SOVERSION properties, but these don't seem to correlate to the FileVersion information I was expecting.

```
set(LIC_TARGET MySharedLib)
add_library(${LIC_TARGET} SHARED ${SOURCES} )

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${LIC_TARGET}
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER}.${MY_PRODUCT_VERSION}.${MY_BUILD_NUMBER}
    SOVERSION ${MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER})
```

I've found [manual methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) (see example at the bottom) but would prefer to contain this within CMake.

Help?

Comment: The example in the "manual methods" link is missing one important line:

`#include <windows.h>`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use your CMake variable values in conjunction with a **version.rc.in** file and the [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command.

```
// version.rc.in
#define VER_FILEVERSION             @MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER@,@MY_PRODUCT_VERSION@,@MY_BUILD_NUMBER@,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "@MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER@.@MY_PRODUCT_VERSION@.@MY_BUILD_NUMBER@.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          @MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER@,@MY_PRODUCT_VERSION@,@MY_BUILD_NUMBER@,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "@MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER@.@MY_PRODUCT_VERSION@.@MY_BUILD_NUMBER@\0"
//
// ...along with the rest of the file from your "manual methods" reference
```

And then, in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(MY_PRODUCT_NUMBER 3)
set(MY_PRODUCT_VERSION 5)
set(MY_BUILD_NUMBER 49)

configure_file(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.rc.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc
  @ONLY)

set(LIC_TARGET MySharedLib)
add_library(${LIC_TARGET} SHARED ${SOURCES}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc)

# Alternatively you could simply include version.rc in another rc file
# if there already is one in one of the files in ${SOURCES}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is much more integrated than manually preparing the rc file first.

Answer (score 17):

I'm had same problem and have automated version generation for my projects.
You need three files from github:

- [generate_product_version.cmake](https://github.com/halex2005/CMakeHelpers/blob/master/generate_product_version.cmake)
- [VersionInfo.in](https://github.com/halex2005/CMakeHelpers/blob/master/VersionInfo.in)
- [VersionResource.rc](https://github.com/halex2005/CMakeHelpers/blob/master/VersionResource.rc)

Put it in cmake subdirectory of your project and make sure to include it to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH like:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
```

Then before add_executable() or add_library(SHARED) your target, use:

```
include(generate_product_version)
generate_product_version(
   VersionFilesOutputVariable
   NAME "My Great Project"
   ICON ${PATH_TO_APPLICATION_ICON}
   VERSION_MAJOR 1
   VERSION_MINOR 3
   VERSION_PATCH ${BUILD_COUNTER}
   VERSION_REVISION ${BUILD_REVISION}
)
```

Full list of supported resource strings see in [generate_product_version.cmake](https://github.com/halex2005/CMakeHelpers/blob/master/generate_product_version.cmake).

VersionInfo.h and VersionResource.rc will be generated to cmake binaries folder. Variable VersionFilesOutputVariable will hold paths to these files. Just add this list to your target:

```
add_executable(MyGreatProject ${your-target-sources} ${VersionFilesOutputVariable})
```

**UPDATE**: Corrected generate_product_version script parameters from VERSION_PATH 
to VERSION_PATCH.

Comment: This generates binaries with 'russian' as language - which may not be appropriate. BLOCK "040904b0" changes that to english. It also can't be used if you have several targets in one CmakeList.txt, which I've added for our use here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/2d23ce989c1247708fba0640d48b52b04ece175c

Comment: AFAIK, to generate nonlocalized version info, we should change translation value which is in VersionResource.rc to: `VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252`. Otherwise some info cannot be produced correctly, such as company name. As well, we cannot get correct version info from powersehell unless we did this change.

Answer (score 9):

There is an even easier way than the accepted answer. It does not involve transforming an input resource.rc.in. Simply create a generic version.rc file as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) and then from your CMakeLists.txt do this:

```
#CMakeLists.txt

add_definitions(-DVER_COMPANYNAME_STR="MyCompany")
add_definitions(-DVER_FILEVERSION_STR="1,1,0.0")
# ...
# add all the other defines here

set(LIC_TARGET MySharedLib)
add_library(${LIC_TARGET} SHARED ${SOURCES} version.rc)
```

This has the added benefit that the defines are accessible from your source code as well, so you have programmatic access to your version.

Comment: I like this idea, but note that updating the .rc file will only require a relink.
Updating -D definitions requires a relink as well as rebuilding any affected source files... potentially much slower.

Comment: Also note that you can programmatically get the version number via MS's GetFileVersionInfo API.  No need for #define on the MS platform.  But this way is still pretty good for cross-platform flexibility.

Comment: Although you can use set_source_files_properties() in cmake to only set those definitions on the .rc file.

Comment: is this a feature of cmake on nmake or cmake on visual studio (and thus not usable by cmake on mingw)?

Comment: @Groostav .rc files are Windows only. The defines are just C definitions, therefore cross platform.

Comment: @Alf what is MySharedLib supposed to be?

Comment: @dstew This is the Windows DLL you are trying to build (see the OP).