# RC file info: Language Neutral

Tags: windows, dll

Some dll declare the Language to be "Language Neutral", at least I saw it on a few dll from C# projects:

[image]

I'd like to do the same for a c++ project, so what is the value for this special language in rc file. Currently I have it set like this ([see previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57800503/136285)):

```
BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409, 1252
END
```

Which leads to English as:

[image]

The value for this "Neutral" language is not defined in the oneline documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource#langID

Comment: If this DLL's "details" page was labeled English, but the resources themselves were actually language neutral, then does it actually matter?

Answer (score 6):

After some quick online search I was able to find the solution myself:

[image]

Complete example:

```
// version.rc.in
#define VER_FILEVERSION             3,5,49,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.5.49.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          3,5,49,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "3.5.49\0"
//

1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "040904E4" // U.S. English - multilingual (hex)
    BEGIN
      VALUE "FileVersion", VER_FILEVERSION_STR
      VALUE "ProductVersion", VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
    END
  END
  /* For some reason the ProductVersion would not appear unless I add */
  /* the following section: VarFileInfo */
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0, 1252 // language neutral - multilingual (decimal)
  END
END
```

Inspiration from:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoind-res.rc