# Set application version on qt?

Tags: qt, version, release

The application version i setted it is not displayed on the properties of the created .exe file.
I use cmake not .pro file.

```
QApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0.0");
```

Comment: If you're on Windows, you should consider using a resource file that defines the application's icon, version and other properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693100/how-to-generate-windows-dll-versioning-information-with-cmake

Comment: ok maybe it's a silly question, but what i don't understand is where do i put the .rc file in the cmake commands?

Comment: Did you look into the question I referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693100/how-to-generate-windows-dll-versioning-information-with-cmake ?

Comment: yess, but i'm not working with a dll, i want to create a simple application and set the version. adding the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc to the add_executable comand made the building fail

Comment: I found the solution to my problem here: [How do I generate Windows DLL versioning information with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791746/how-do-i-generate-windows-dll-versioning-information-with-cmake)