# How can I add version information to Boost DLLs when building Boost?

Tags: windows, boost, dll, versioning, bjam

I recently created a Jenkins Pipeline to build `Boost 1.68.0` for Windows. I'm using Boost's build system (`Bjam`) in my Pipeline. Everything is working properly, but the DLLs generated by my Pipeline are missing the following information, which can be viewed by right clicking them and navigating to the `Details` tab:

- File version
- Product name
- Product version

I have faced this issue before when working with libraries that use `CMake` in their build process, and fixing it can be achieved by creating a `version.rc` file with the necessary information, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693100/how-to-generate-windows-dll-versioning-information-with-cmake).

So my question is: is there a way to do the same with `Bjam`? I have been searching online for a while, but I can't find any information on this topic. Thank you for any information!