# Adding Copyright / File description info to dll when compiling with cmake

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, cmake

I need to add information to C++ DLL's that I'm generating via CMake, without using a third party tool.
I've tried adding a version.rc file to my directory and including it in the CMakeLists file, but it doesn't appear to populate the fields on the DLL information box.

CMakeLists:

```
configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.rc.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.rc
        @ONLY
)


add_library(foo SHARED
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.rc)
)
```

version.rc

```
#define VER_FILEVERSION             3,10,349,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "3.10.349.0\0"

#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          3,10,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "3.10\0"

#ifndef DEBUG
#define VER_DEBUG                   0
#else
#define VER_DEBUG                   VS_FF_DEBUG
#endif

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
         
            VALUE "FileVersion",      VER_FILEVERSION_STR

            VALUE "ProductVersion",   VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        /* The following line should only be modified for localized versions.     */
        /* It consists of any number of WORD,WORD pairs, with each pair           */
        /* describing a language,codepage combination supported by the file.      */
        /*                                                                        */
        /* For example, a file might have values "0x409,1252" indicating that it  */
        /* supports English language (0x409) in the Windows ANSI codepage (1252). */

        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252

    END
END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to show a [mcve], in your case the version resource file and the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: This may happen because your dll has no source files and nothing to export. Or was the example reduced too much?

Comment: Related to the question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699020/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699020/487892)

Comment: @drescherjm example is super reduced. DLL is exported as expected in environment, just not with details attached to properties like I expected.

Comment: Hi,@RedSharpie, did you solve this issue and did the answer help you？

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer why it is not working in your case. I suppose the format of the resource file is not valid or you are missing essential field information form the versioninfo block.

A versioninfo resource template (`versioninfo.rc.cmake.in`) that is known to work from another project looks as follows:

```
1 TYPELIB "versioninfo.rc"

1 VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION @PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@, 0
 PRODUCTVERSION @PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@, 0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904e4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Foonatic Ltd."
            VALUE "FileDescription", "foobar library - https://github.com/foobar/"
            VALUE "FileVersion","@PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@, 0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "@PROJECT_NAME@"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (c) 2020 Foonatic Ltd."
#ifdef _DEBUG
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "foobarD.dll"
#else
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "foobar.dll"
#endif
            VALUE "ProductName", "foobar"
            VALUE "ProductVersion","@PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR@, @PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH@, 0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

It is processed by `configure_file` command into `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/versioninfo.rc.cmake.in versioninfo.rc @ONLY)
```

and added with either

```
add_library(dll_target_name SHARED dll_source.cpp "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/versioninfo.rc")
```

or

```
target_sources(dll_target_name PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/versioninfo.rc")
```

to the DLL target.